# Typescript '{ readonly id: number... is missing the following properties from type 'Product': _id

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typeerror, pinia

Typescript is throwing an error when attempting to return my custom class object for not matching the specified return type. The error is as follows:

> TS2739: Type '{ readonly id: number; readonly productName: string; readonly price: number; readonly displayPrice: string; readonly images: string[]; toString: () => string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': _id, _productName, _price, _images

I created a custom Product class with corresponding getters like below:

```js
export default class Product {

    private readonly _id: number
    private readonly _productName: string
    private readonly _price: number
    private readonly _images: string[]

    constructor(id: number, productName: string, price: number,
                image0: string, image1?: string, image2?: string,
                image3?: string, image4?: string, image5?: string) {
        this._id = id
        this._productName = productName
        this._price = price
        this._images = [ image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5 ]
...
```

And then I have a pinia function which iterates through a list of products and returns one:

```js
    state: () => {
        return {
            size: 0,
            products: [] as Product[]
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getProductById(id: Number): Product | null {
            for (const item of this.products) {
                if (id == item.id) {
                    return item   //Typescript error generated here
                }
            }
            return null
        },
```

As far as I can tell, the type of "item" should clearly be type Product which matches the return type and has the associated properties -  "_id, _productName, _price, _images" - that Typescript is warning about not having.
However, it seems the return type "Product" of `getProductById()` isn't matching the type of the values inside the `products` array.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Even based on the typescript error, it seems like all values are present.

Comment: `item._id` is what you wanted to compare perhaps?

Comment: No I'm trying to return the whole object.

Comment: Found [this pinia topic](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1178) but honestly not sure what to make of it.